# How do I create multiple regression models (statsmodel) in subsets of a pandas data frame using a for loop or conditon?

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, classification, regression

How do I create multiple regression models (statsmodel) in subsets of a pandas data frame using a for loop or conditon?

I have a datframe which has one variable state that has 51 unique values. I have to make a model for each state. For some reason I am limited to regression(statsmodel)
lets say with variable V1 to be predicted by variables X1 , X2, X3

State is 1:51 and will be used as condition to split that dataframe

How can I automate this task using a for loop ?

Comment: so, internally you want the dataframe to split into 51 small dataframes, each catering to one of the 51states, and then build 51 models on it...right ?

Comment: that is correct. I however want to focus on the model interpretation part rather than doing the same thing 51 times

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are only concerned with looping and not splitting the dataframes into 51 subparts, here is my attempt to your question:

Lets say, you define your OLS function as:

```
def OLSfunction(y):

    y_train = traindf[y]
    y_test = testdf[y]
    from statsmodels.api import OLS
    x_train = x_traindf
    x_test = x_testdf
    model = OLS(y_train, x_train)
    result = model.fit()
    print (result.summary())
    pred_OLS = result.predict(x_test)
    print("R2", r2_score(y_test, pred_OLS))



Y_s = ['1','2',.....'51']
for y in Y_s:
    y=y
    OLSfunction(y)
```

Please note you will have to have your traindf and testdf appropriately derived for the specific Y you are looking to build the model.
And these will have to be correctly passed into the OLSfunction.
Since I do not have any view of how your data looks like, am not getting into splitting/creation of traindf/ testdf...

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import os as os
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.formula.api as sm
```

First I created a dict to hold the 51 datasets

```
d = {}
for x in range(0, 52):
    d[x]=ccf.loc[ccf['state'] == x]

d.keys()

dict_keys([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51])
```

To check

```
d[1].head()
```

Then I ran the code in a loop using position in the dict

```
results={}
for x in range(1, 51):
        results[x] = sm.Logit(d[x].fraudRisk, d[x][names]).fit().summary2()
```

However I felt I should use the multiple classifiers in sklearn. First I need to split the data as pointed above.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

# Multiple Models
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier  
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier 
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB

#Model Metrics
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score


lr={}
gnb={}
svc={}
rfc={}
classifier={}
regr_1={}
regr_2={}
import datetime 
datetime.datetime.now() 

for x in range(1, 51):
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(d[x][names], d[x].fraudRisk, test_size=0.3)
    print(len(X_train))
    print(len(y_test))

    # Create classifiers

    lr[x] = LogisticRegression().fit(X_train, y_train).predict(X_test)
    gnb[x] = GaussianNB().fit(X_train, y_train).predict(X_test)
    svc[x] = LinearSVC(C=1.0).fit(X_train, y_train).predict(X_test)
    rfc[x] = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=1).fit(X_train, y_train).predict(X_test)
    classifier[x] = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=3).fit(X_train, y_train).predict(X_test)  

    print(datetime.datetime.now())
    print("Accuracy Score for model for  state ",x, 'is  ')

    print('LogisticRegression',accuracy_score(y_test,lr[x]))
    print('GaussianNB',accuracy_score(y_test,gnb[x]))
    print('LinearSVC',accuracy_score(y_test,svc[x]))
    print('RandomForestClassifier',accuracy_score(y_test,rfc[x]))
    print('KNeighborsClassifier',accuracy_score(y_test,classifier[x]))

    print("Classification Report for model for state ",x, 'is  ')

    print('LogisticRegression',classification_report(y_test,lr[x]))
    print('GaussianNB',classification_report(y_test,gnb[x]))
    print('LinearSVC',classification_report(y_test,svc[x]))
    print('RandomForestClassifier',classification_report(y_test,rfc[x]))
    print('KNeighborsClassifier',classification_report(y_test,classifier[x]))

    print("Confusion Matrix Report for model for state ",x, 'is  ')  

    print('LogisticRegression',confusion_matrix(y_test,lr[x]))
    print('GaussianNB',confusion_matrix(y_test,gnb[x]))
    print('LinearSVC',confusion_matrix(y_test,svc[x]))
    print('RandomForestClassifier',confusion_matrix(y_test,rfc[x]))
    print('KNeighborsClassifier',confusion_matrix(y_test,classifier[x]))

    print("Area Under Curve for model for state ",x, 'is  ') 

    print('LogisticRegression',roc_auc_score(y_test,lr[x]))
    print('GaussianNB',roc_auc_score(y_test,gnb[x]))
    print('LinearSVC',roc_auc_score(y_test,svc[x]))
    print('RandomForestClassifier',roc_auc_score(y_test,rfc[x]))
    print('KNeighborsClassifier',roc_auc_score(y_test,classifier[x]))
```

Took a long time for 5 models X 51 states with multiple metrics but was worth it. Let me know if there is a faster or better way to write more elegant and less hacky code